# Cannot delete due to linked question - Weird dialog behavior

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, linked-questions

I tried to delete a question that was tagged as a duplicate of another question (and already had 2 delete votes) and saw this:

[image]

So I clicked the "View duplicate questions" button and saw this

[image]

I believe that one's Ignored Tags preference should not apply on this page.

If this is a regression or unexpected behavior, then please consider this a bug report.

If this is currently behaving as designed, then please consider this a feature request.

Comment: It is unclear what bug you are reporting and/or what feature you are requesting. Can you please narrow/clarify your question to be a clear feature-request or bug report about one problem?

Comment: @TylerH It sounds clear to me that Jim wants a way to list all linked questions (including those from your ignored tags, excluding not linked questions).

Comment: @Cœur I guess I should clarify for yours and others' sakes - this post is not likely to be acted upon in its current, muddled state. It should be a feature request *or* a bug, *and* focus on one thing, not two. If it is a bug, then there's no need to tag it as a feature-request, as that's implicit in the fixing of the bug.

Comment: @TylerH I've kept the [`[bug]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug), because it seems to be a regression from a design change.

Comment: @TylerH I've removed the second half and focused only on the possible bug.  If the behavior is working as currently designed, then consider this  a Feature Request.